# How to properly add spacing between collection view cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently trying to set spacing between my collection view cells. The issue is every time I scroll horizontally the cell does not reset back to where is should be. I'm using this library for the collection view cell animation: https://github.com/KelvinJin/AnimatedCollectionViewLayout.

Please Look at image bellow!

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Turn on the paging mode for auto snaping support.
    collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true

    if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? AnimatedCollectionViewLayout {
        layout.scrollDirection = direction
        layout.animator = animator?.0
    }

    dismissGesture.direction = direction == .horizontal ? .down : .left
}

extension ImageCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(Int16.max)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    if let cell = c as? SimpleCollectionViewCell {
        let i = indexPath.row % vcs.count
        let v = vcs[i]
        cell.bind(color: v.0, imageName: v.1)
        cell.clipsToBounds = animator?.1 ?? true
    }

    return c
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    guard let animator = animator else { return view.bounds.size }
    return CGSize(width: view.bounds.width / CGFloat(animator.2), height: view.bounds.height / CGFloat(animator.3))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return .zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

}

Also here are images showing what happens:

[image]

Comment: Did you set ispagingenabled for the collectionview?

Comment: @Mark Yes paging is enabled. Please take a look at my post as I added more code. Specifically in viewDidLoad paging is enabled.

Comment: Why you set 10pt of spacing?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio I want that amount of spacing when I scroll between the images.

Comment: Could you add code related to `animator` and `direction` properties?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio please click the link of the library I'm using. They have a sample project so you can have access to everything.

Comment: Which animation are you trying?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio Parallax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189747/discussion-between-rico-crescenzio-and-user7097242).

Comment: This might be obvious, but you might check the "Min Spacing" value in the Storyboard Size inspector for your UICollectionview. It usually have 10 by default, just make sure its 0.